# How to set HTML parameters via Jquery script?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to apply **Bootstrap-select** plugin to my MVC 5 application. In fact, it is working, but I can't customize it because in documentation examples are given as HTML parameters and I do not know how to apply them to my razor view.

Here is my cshtml dropdownlist:

```
`@Html.DropDownList("Suppliers", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.Suppliers, 
"SupplierID", "Name"), new { multiple = "multiple", @class = "selectpicker" })`
```

Here is my script:

```
`<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$(".selectpicker").selectpicker('selectAll');
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ liveSearch: true, ac });
    });
</script>`
```

Here is an example of an HTML parameter:

```
`<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
 <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
 <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
 <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>`
```

I need to apply `data-live-search="true"` parameter to my dropdownlist.

Link to Bootstrap-select: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.selectpicker').attr('data-live-search', true)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker">
  <option data-tokens="ketchup mustard">Hot Dog, Fries and a Soda</option>
  <option data-tokens="mustard">Burger, Shake and a Smile</option>
  <option data-tokens="frosting">Sugar, Spice and all things nice</option>
</select>
```